# woocommerce disable ajax fragments for cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

**Update**
i need to disable woocommerce ajax fragments only for coupons, without affect other functionality.
Need to update cart totals without problem with ajax, but when we add or remove coupons, to not have ajax.

I write this code for now, who make my cart page to reload when i apply or remove coupon.

```
add_action('wp_footer', function () {

    ?> <script>
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url === '/?wc-ajax=apply_coupon' || settings.url === '/?wc-ajax=remove_coupon') {
        location.reload();
    }
});
   </script><?php
});
```

How i can remove coupons ajax using?
maybe something like:

```
remove_action for wp_ajax_coupon & wp_ajax_nopriv_coupon
```

Thanks

Comment: Without any code and clear question there is not a developer in the exsitance that can help you

Comment: @Mr.Phantom thank you, i have updated status.